# excel vba sub script out of bound error

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to get the output of following code but its giving out error

Following is the code:

---

```
Dim strRisk() As String
Dim riskLen As Integer

strRisk = SplitMultiDelims(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value, "@")
MsgBox UBound(strRisk)
```

Error:

---

```
Run time error '9':
Subscript out of range
```

The value in the refering cell is not null, what else could be the reason? is there another way to do this.

Please help me out

Comment: You'll probably need to share your code for SplitMultiDelims as well, most likely it's not properly returning an array needed for strRisk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define `Dim strRisk() As String` as a dynamic array, then you need `Redim strRisk (n)` and further refer to strRisk with a corresponding index: `strRisk(i)=....`

If you want to store strRisk as array, use `Dim strRisk As Variant`, then 
`strRisk=...` will work.

Comment: I am with you. @roshank test this: `strRisk = Array("10", "20", "30")` -> it fails, except strRisk is a Variant or you use it like Jüri suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Add a BreakPoint on the line that begins `strRisk` and then run the code.

If you now run the line `Excel.ActiveCell(0, 9).select` in the Immediate Window is it definitely the cell you wish this code to target?